# how to enable PCI passthru for NIC (or SR-IOV) on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, hp, pci

I have a DL380p G9 with 4port onboard NIC adapter. While the manufacturer says it supports SR-IOV. I am not seeing the capabilities in the OS command output. I intend to use 3 ports for VMs and 1 port for host.

How can I get this adapter to support PCI PAssthrough (or SR-IOV)?

Thank you.

NIC:

```
# lspci -nn|grep Ether
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
02:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
02:00.3 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
```

Vendor:
at: https://www.broadcom.com/products/ethernet-connectivity/network-adapters/bcm5719-1gbase-t-ic

> The host interface supports a separate PCI Express function for each
> LAN interface. The BCM5719 includes I/O Virtualization (IOV) features
> such as 17 receive and 16 transmit queues, and 17 MSI-X vectors with
> flexible vector-to-queue association. These IOV features enable the
> BCM5719 to support the VMWare® NetQueue and Microsoft® VMQ
> technologies.

per HP:
https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c04249126&docLocale=en_US

> For HP Broadcom NICs that support Single Root I/O Virtualization
> (SR-IOV), virtual functions can be created on the virtualization hosts
> and assigned to the virtualized guests.

in the OS:

```
# lspci -vvv -s 02:00.0
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
        DeviceName: Embedded LOM 1 Port 1
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 331i Adapter
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
        NUMA node: 0
        Region 0: Memory at 92b90000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Region 2: Memory at 92ba0000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Region 4: Memory at 92bb0000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Expansion ROM at 93000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=256K]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
        Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
                Product Name: HPE Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 331i Adapter
                Read-only fields:
                        [PN] Part number: N/A
                        [EC] Engineering changes: A-5427
                        [SN] Serial number: N/A
                        [MN] Manufacture ID: 103C
                        [V0] Vendor specific: 5W PCIeGen2
                        [V1] Vendor specific: 21.6.28
                        [V2] Vendor specific: N/A
                        [V3] Vendor specific: 1.46
                        [V5] Vendor specific: 0A
                        [V6] Vendor specific: 21.6.0
                        [V7] Vendor specific: 331i
                        [VA] Vendor specific: 20.19.51
                        [RV] Reserved: checksum good, 215 byte(s) reserved
                Read/write fields:
                        [RW] Read-write area: 10 byte(s) free
                End
        Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=17 Masked-
                Vector table: BAR=4 offset=00000000
                PBA: BAR=4 offset=00001000
        Capabilities: [ac] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr+ FatalErr+ UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr+ NoSnoop- FLReset-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x4, ASPM not supported
                        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x2 (downgraded)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR-
                         10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- OBFF Disabled,
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
                         Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        Capabilities: [13c v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-ec-b1-d7-7f-9a-90
        Capabilities: [150 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [160 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Kernel driver in use: tg3
        Kernel modules: tg3
```

I am not seeing the capabilities. Is it a driver issue?

++adding BIOS screenshots:

[image: BIOS setting - 1]

[image: BIOS Network setting - 2]

[image: BIOS settings - 3]

Answer (score 1):

Ans is: it cannot be done. The advertised SR-IOV capability is only form VMWare and Windows. No support for Linux :-(

from docs: [BCM5719 doc](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/57194P-DS103)

> I/O Virtualization support for VMWare NetQueue and Microsoft VMQ
>
> – 17 receive queues and 16 transmit queues per port
>
> – 17 MSI-X vectors supporting per queue interrupt to host

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to enable the SR-IOV feature inside the System Utilities and set the max VFs per card inside the BIOS itself before seeing the num_vfs on the kernel.

BIOS setting:

[image: Bios Setting]

Comment: Thank you. But I do not see this in my BIOS. I have iLO 4. Your output seem to be from Gen10.